# Is there an efficient way to do a vertical lookup kind of task in AWK using multiple files?

Tags: awk

I am struggling a lot with the following task which I currently try to accomplish using AWK. I am not very familiar with AWK so I am not even sure if AWK is the best for this. If this is better to be solved with Python, please let me know (but I know even less of Python).

I need to prepare an input file for an analysis which is based on collecting gene expression P-values of multiple species from different files. For each species there are multiple treatment files.

**In brief: I need to collect P-values linked to sequenceIDs from multiple files and put them in a single file ordered per Orthogroup. For each Orthogroup I only need to keep the lowest P-value per species treatment file**

Orthogroupfile: A list of all orthogroups: on each line one orthogroup, every column is a sequenceID, 1st column is the orthogroupID.

```
OG0052916: TRINITY_TN_DN99904_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN38054_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN41618_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN47300_c0_g1
OG0001002: TRINITY_AG_DN119624_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN161549_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN60596_c0_g1 TRINITY_MB_DN61252_c1_g1 TRINITY_SE_DN51134_c2_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN27816_c0_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN76945_c4_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN77747_c0_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN77747_c1_g1 TRINITY_TN_DN52316_c0_g1
OG0002002: TRINITY_AG_DN56841_c0_g1 TRINITY_MB_DN200880_c1_g1 TRINITY_SE_DN45370_c1_g1 TRINITY_SE_DN53999_c0_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN16333_c0_g1 TRINITY_SL_DN65991_c0_g1 TRINITY_TN_DN180200_c0_g1 TRINITY_TN_DN48658_c0_g1
OG0052920: TRINITY_TN_DN99983_c0_g1 TRINITY_AG_DN12345_c0_g1
```

Speciesfile: For each species I have a separate file summarising differential gene expression data. But for every species I have multiple treatments and thus multiple species treatment files. For me important is the P-value (10th column) and the sequence ID (1st column). Each species in the analysis has such a file, the two-letter code in the sequence IDs is a species code ("AG", "TN", "SE", "SL", "MB")

Speciesfile treatment 1 e.g. AG.txt:

AG.txt:

```
TRINITY_AG_DN38054_c0_g1    0.364813449
TRINITY_AG_DN41618_c0_g1    0.000130019
TRINITY_AG_DN47300_c0_g1    0.000195804
TRINITY_AG_DN119624_c0_g1   0.067
TRINITY_AG_DN161549_c0_g1   0.00036
TRINITY_AG_DN60596_c0_g1    0.023
TRINITY_AG_DN12345_c0_g1    NA
TRINITY_AG_DN56841_c0_g1    0.034
```

Speciesfile treatment 2 e.g. AA.txt:

```
TRINITY_AG_DN38054_c0_g1        3.364813449e-07
TRINITY_AG_DN41618_c0_g1        6.000130019e-03
TRINITY_AG_DN47300_c0_g1        8.000195804e-02
TRINITY_AG_DN119624_c0_g1       5.067e-05
TRINITY_AG_DN161549_c0_g1       5.00036e-06
TRINITY_AG_DN60596_c0_g1        4.023e-7
TRINITY_AG_DN12345_c0_g1        0.03
TRINITY_AG_DN56841_c0_g1        2.034e-2
```

Speciesfile treatment 1 e.g. TN.txt:

```
TRINITY_TN_DN99904_c0_g1    0.005
TRINITY_TN_DN99983_c0_g1    0.063
TRINITY_TN_DN180200_c0_g1   0.0326
TRINITY_TN_DN48658_c0_g1    0.02762
TRINITY_TN_DN52316_c0_g1    0.000737267
```

speciesfile treatment 2 e.g. TA.txt

```
TRINITY_TN_DN99904_c0_g1        6.005e-4
TRINITY_TN_DN99983_c0_g1        9.063e-03
TRINITY_TN_DN180200_c0_g1       1.0326e-1
TRINITY_TN_DN48658_c0_g1        3.02762e-09
TRINITY_TN_DN52316_c0_g1        2.000737267e-10
```

MB.txt:

```
TRINITY_MB_DN61252_c1_g1    0.0004378
TRINITY_MB_DN200880_c1_g1   0.00007281
```

SE.txt:

```
TRINITY_SE_DN51134_c2_g1    0.0007367
TRINITY_SE_DN53999_c0_g1    0.00376
TRINITY_SE_DN45370_c1_g1    0.00067356
```

The output file that I need “summarises” information from the different species with a Orthogroup on each line. I am only interested in the P-values

1. First column: Orthogroup ID
2. Second column: lowest P-value (for all
   genes of sp1 in this Orthogroup e.g. "AG", so this is species treatment file dependent )
3. Third column: total nr.
   of genes of sp1 in this Orthogroup (this will be similar for different   treatments of the same species)
4. Fourth column: total number of
   genes for sp1. in the cluster (but this can always be the same as
   the third column)

The next three columns is than repeating the same for the other species, and continues afterwards. NA if there are no genes present of that species in that orthogroup

Example output.txt, which includes the P-value information for all different species "AG", "MB", "TN", "SE" and "SL":

```
Group   AG-Pvalue   AG-nGenes   AG-ClusterSize  MB-Pvalue   MB-nGenes   MB-ClusterSize  SE-Pvalue   SE-nGenes   SE-ClusterSize  TN-Pvalue   TN-nGenes   TN-ClusterSize  AA-Pvalue       AA-nGenes       AA-ClusterSize  TA-Pvalue       TA-nGenes       TA-ClusterSize
OG0052916   0.000130019 3   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.005   1   1   3.364813449e-07 3       3       6.005e-4        1   1
OG0002002   0.034   1   1   0.00007281  1   1   0.00067356  3   3   0.02762 2   2   2.034e-2        1       1   3.02762e-09     2       2
OG0001002:  0.00036 3   3   0.0004378   1   1   0.0007367   1   1   0.000737267 1   1   5.067e-05       3       3   2.000737267e-10 1       1
OG0052920:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.063   1   1   0.03    1   1   9.063e-03       1       1
```

"Next-Orthogroup" "lowest P-value of the diet treatment per species" "nr of genes of this species in this orthogroup"

- I realise this problem consists of 3 different problems:

  - 1 a simple vertical look-up
  - 2 a if - then choice, if multiple genes in Orthogroup than copy the lowest P-value
  - 3 calculate the number of genes per species per Orthogroup.

I wanted to tackle this one by one, but failed already at the first step:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1 in a {print $10}’ Orthogroups1.txt TN.txt
```

Check all columns of file 1 for occurrence in file 2 and print the 10th column.

If anyone could help me with the above? Even if it is just a direction, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded Answer, to address additional data files, per additional information from OP:

Invoke with list of species/treatments, the indicator 'DATA=1', and the data file.

```
script.awk  AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TN.txt AA.txt TA.txt DATA=1 data.txt
```

script.awk

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
!DATA {
    # Calculate key from file name
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
            ncol++
            k = gensub("(.*/)?([^/]+)\\.([^/]*)$", "\\2", 1, FILENAME)
            cols[ncol] = k
    }
    v[k, $1] = $2
    # Track keys
    ccount[k]++
    next
}
{
    g=$1                    # Group

    # Calculate count, min per group
    for (i=2 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
        id=$i
        split(id, parts, "_")
        for (k in cols) {
            ss = cols[k]
            val = v[ss, id]
            if ( !val ) continue
            if ( !vcount[g, ss] ||  val < vmin[g, ss] ) vmin[g, ss] = val
            vcount[g, ss]++
            gcount[g, ss]++
            group[g]++
#    print "SET", id, g, ss, val, vmin[g,ss], vcount[g, ss]
        }
    }
}

END {
    # Header Line
    printf "%s", "group"
    for (k in cols) {
        ss = cols[k]
        printf " %s-PValue %s-nGenees %s-ClusterSize", ss, ss, ss
    }
    printf "\n"

    # Print line
    ng = 0
    for (g in group) {
        ng++
        printf "%s", g
        for (k in cols) {
            ss = cols[k]
            s_min = vmin[g, ss]
            s_count = vcount[g, ss]
            s_cs = gcount[g, ss]
#        print "GET", g, ss, vmin[g, ss], vcount[g, ss], "X"
            if ( !s_count ) { s_count = s_min = s_cs = "NA" }
            printf " %s %s %s", s_min, s_count, s_cs
#            printf " %s %d %d", vmin[g, ss] ? vmin[g, ss] : "NA" , vcount[g, ss], vcount[g, ss]
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    for (k in cols ) {
        ss = cols[k]
        print "Col:", ss, ccount[ss] > "/dev/stderr"
    }
    print "Groups:", ng > "/dev/stderr"

}
```

Output for:

```
awk -f ./script-spcomp.awk AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TN.txt AA.txt TA.txt DATA=1 data.txt
```

```
group AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize SE-PValue SE-nGenees SE-ClusterSize TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize
OG0052920: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.063 1 1 NA NA NA 9.063e-03 1 1
OG0052916: 0.000130019 3 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.005 1 1 3.364813449e-07 3 3 6.005e-4 1 1
OG0002002: 0.034 1 1 0.00007281 1 1 0.00067356 2 2 0.02762 2 2 2.034e-2 1 1 3.02762e-09 2 2
OG0001002: 0.00036 3 3 0.0004378 1 1 0.0007367 1 1 0.000737267 1 1 4.023e-7 3 3 2.000737267e-10 1 1
```

When running with the modified list list of columns, the output is:

```
awk -f script-spcomp.awk TA.txt SE.txt MB.txt AG.txt AA.txt TN.txt DATA=1
```

ortho.txt

```
group TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize SE-PValue SE-nGenees SE-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize
OG0052920: 9.063e-03 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.063 1 1
OG0052916: 6.005e-4 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.000130019 3 3 3.364813449e-07 3 3 0.005 1 1
OG0002002: 3.02762e-09 2 2 0.00067356 2 2 0.00007281 1 1 0.034 1 1 2.034e-2 1 1 0.02762 2 2
OG0001002: 2.000737267e-10 1 1 0.0007367 1 1 0.0004378 1 1 0.00036 3 3 4.023e-7 3 3 0.000737267 1 1
```

Comment: Hi @dash-o , fantastic :-). I was not able to be online last weekend, but working on it now. I get the following error running it locally on the example data:
`bash script-spcomp.awk AG.txt AA.txt MB.txt SE.txt TA.txt TN.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt 
script-spcomp.awk: line 2: !DATA: command not found
script-spcomp.awk: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token ``{'
script-spcomp.awk: line 4: `   if ( FNR == 1 ) {' `
I might have simply overlooked something, but cannot figure out where I did make a mistake neither with help from google. Can you give it a quick look?

Comment: This is an `awk` script, you can launch with `awk script-pscomp.awk AG.txt ...`

Comment: it did work indeed, but had to add "-f", with just awk "script" it was not running as tried before. The script runs but with the multiple treatment files per species it give a wrong value for one of the treatments. For TA and TN, TA is all fine but for TN it gives the lower P-value as P-value TA-1 instead of the lowest P-value for TN. And similar for the AG / AA combination, example:
`OG0052916: NA NA NA 6.005e-4 1 1 5.005e-4 1 1 2.364813449e-07 3 3 3.364813449e-07 3 3 NA NA NA`

Comment: @T_R Can you (1) share the command line that you use (2) highlight the wrong entry - line #, column #, and value (3) provide the expected value. I'm not sure I fully understand `TA-1`, etc.

Comment: Sure! Command: `awk -f script-spcomp.awk AA.txt AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TA.txt TN.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt`

Comment: Sure! Command: `awk -f script-spcomp.awk AA.txt AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TA.txt TN.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt` output of the first header line and just a single wrong orthogroupline: `SE-PValue SE-nGenees SE-ClusterSize TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize
OG0052916: NA NA NA 6.005e-4 1 1 5.005e-4 1 1 3.364813449e-07 3 3 2.364813449e-07 3 3 NA NA NA`

Correct is: `OG0052916: NA NA NA 6.005e-4 1 1 0.005 1 1 3.364813449e-07 3 3 0.000130019 3 3 NA NA NA`

Comment: Can you check if you run the correct group. The order of columns in output (SE, TA, TN, ...) is different from the order of input files (AA, AG, MB). The script write output in same order as input. Can you verify you are testing the latest posted code ?

Comment: Not in my case though! I refreshed everything again, but running it does result in the same order as follows: `awk -f script-spcomp.awk AA.txt AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TA.txt TN.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt`
And with the resulting order: `SE-PValue SE-nGenees SE-ClusterSize TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize` But the order for me is not an issue, it is just the given values thats odd because it automatically does '-1'

Comment: Update, changing the order does change the output, it simply does not start at the first input file! :-) command: `awk -f script-spcomp.awk TA.txt SE.txt MB.txt AG.txt AA.txt TN.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt` output:
`group AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize SE-PValue SE-nGenees SE-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize`

Comment: sorry, was out for Christmas, can you perhaps have a final look to the above problem? The ordering and printing of the correct Pvalues seems not to work properly yet.

Comment: I have tried to optimise the code myself without luck, the only result is that I get no output. Is there perhaps someone or ideally @dash-o (if this reaches you) who could help me with the final improvement of the code so that the ordering issue including the output of the wrong P-value gets solved (see above)?

Comment: @T_R Can you check that you use the latest posted script. It produce the columns in the order of the ??.txt files. In your example, the first columns are AG, implying that this one of the earlier versions which was using inline list of species.

Comment: @T_R Happy new year! Hope we can get this done for you

Comment: All the best for 2020 for you too! Running the script on the posted data does result in the correct output. But the columns are still different from how I call them in the command line. However, for me this is no problem but it is strange of course! The output always start with the 4th given input file: `awk -f ./script.awk AG.txt MB.txt SE.txt TN.txt AA.txt TA.txt DATA=1 ortho.txt` order: `TN-PValue TN-nGenees TN-ClusterSize AA-PValue AA-nGenees AA-ClusterSize TA-PValue TA-nGenees TA-ClusterSize AG-PValue AG-nGenees AG-ClusterSize MB-PValue MB-nGenees MB-ClusterSize SE-PValue`

Comment: just run the script on part of my "real real" data and did a quick check.. The output perfect as far as I can see, the data is correct. Still the order of the columns is similarly starting from the third called file, but that is ok. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have noticed one final issue while running the script on my dataset and I am not been able to solve it. In the species files there are occasions that a gene ID is given with: "Pvalue NA". This results in the output file in a `NA 1 1` record of that specific gene for that species, while this should be `0 0 0`. Is it possible to filter out all "NA 1 1" occasions in the end? I have updated the example input files above to illustrate this. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @ dash-o just to track the change: in group "OG52920" species-treatment "AG" has gene "TRINITY_AG_DN12345_c0_g1" as "NA" so this is not popping up at the final output. But for "AA" this same gene has a p-value of 0.03.

Comment: I am not even sure if this final issue is reaching you or anyone that could help with this AWK script? In case it does, I did try to solve it by editing the final output (filtering the wrongly NA 1 1 and changing it into NA NA NA), but this is not ideal nor efficient.
I've also seen that in the comments above of Jan 10 at 10.40, I am saying that the NA 1 1 should be 0 0 0. I think this automatically changed instead of 0 0 0, it should read 3x NA (NA NA NA). As in the posted and edited example.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @T_R Can you clarify what is wrong with the GC52920 Output ? line is '9.063e-03 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.063 1 1', I can not see 'NA 1 1' in the output.

Comment: I fully understand, I signed up for coding workshops to really get to know it. For now its a very steep learning curve, and so far always trying to solve things myself. I am learning it, but with all the help I get I learn each time a lot too. I'm sorry for the basic knowledge: I get there!
I encountered this problem running the script on my real data, so to visualise this I have updated the posted simulation data. Every time the code encounters a gene for which it says NA (the case for DN12345_c0_g1 in AG.txt), it notes "1" for ngenes and nclusters. While it should be `NA NA NA`.

Comment: So running the script on this data (including the gene `DN12345_c0_g1 NA`, for AG.txt) I get: `OG0052920: 0.063 1 1 0.03 1 1 9.063e-03 1 1 NA 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA`
The `NA 1 1` should read `NA NA NA`. This problem just now popped up from the full dataset, the previous output was correct as long as there are now "gene NA" records.

Comment: It seems that I have solved it by adding an additional statement if a "NA 11" pattern is found it should be changed into "NA NA NA". Thanks again for your extensive help and by sparking up the joy for coding! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following awk script performs the following, based on the question (assuming latest post capture all requirements)

- Load the lookup tables AG.txt, MB.txt, ... (BEGIN block)
- Read the main data file, and find out min, count per group/species.
- Print the output (END block)

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    # Load all XX.txt files
    n_species=split("AG,MB,TN,SE,SL", species, ",")
    for (s in species) {
        sfile = species[s] ".txt"
        nn=0
        while ( (getline < sfile) > 0 ) { v[$1] = $2; nn++ }
        print "Loaded:", sfile, nn > "/dev/stderr"
    }
}
{
    g = $1                  # Group

    # Calculate count, min per group
    for (i=2 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
        id=$i
        split(id, parts, "_")
        ss=parts[2]           # Species
        val = v[id]
        if ( val ) {
                if ( !vcount[g, ss] ||  val < vmin[g, ss] ) vmin[g, ss] = val
                vcount[g, ss]++
                group[g]++
#       print "SET", id, g, ss, val, vmin[g,ss], vcount[g, ss]
        }
    }

}
END {
    # Header Line
    printf "%s", "group"
    for (s in species) {
        ss = species[s]
        printf " %s-PValue %s-nGenees %s-ClusterSize", ss, ss, ss
    }
    printf "\n"

    # Print line
    ng = 0
    for (g in group) {
        ng++
        printf "%s", g
        for (s in species) {
            ss = species[s]
#           print "GET", g, ss, vmin[g, ss], vcount[g, ss], "X"
            s_min = vmin[g, ss]
            s_count = vcount[g, ss]
            s_cs = vcount[g, ss]
            if ( !s_count ) { s_count = s_min = s_cs = "NA" }
            printf " %s %s %s", s_min, s_count, s_cs
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    print "Groups:", ng > "/dev/stderr"

}' < data.txt
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic.. I feel this is super close! But the output stops after wrongly outputting the first line: 
`headers correct
TRINITY NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0
Groups: 1`
So it seems it stops after just the first orthogroup. There are moreover 2 issues: it does not give the orthogroupID but 'TRINITY', and if pvalue is NA than geneNR and clusterNR should be NA also.

Comment: @T_R Is it possible to see problem using posted data ?

Comment: Yes, I will do the same using the posted data now.

Comment: @T_R I've posted a fix to the grouping. Can you try revised script ?

Comment: The revised script does work on the heavily minimised dataset! Fantastic..!
But, I'm just trying to run it on the real data but I only get `NA 0 0` as output. The only difference is the number of sequence information and the number of species files. It seems it does not recognise the links anymore, could this be an issue easily solvable?
example:
`OG0033505: NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0 NA 0 0`

Comment: It works! The problem was a naming issue on my side.. There is just one thing I cannot solve myself: if there is a NA p-value than the number of genes and clustersize should be NA too. Is that easily implementable?

Comment: I've posted the change. If you will have to do similar work, consider reading few intro  articles about using awk. Also, if you have more number crunching/analysis, consider learning Python. It will be good investment for your time

Comment: you are a star! I would buy you a drink :-)
There seems to be one final issue, because this is transcriptomic data sequence names do occur in multiple species files because I treat treatments as separate species. This means that the script should search the sequence names again and again for all the species/treatment files, even if it has found a p-value for one of the files. Would that be a possibility?

Comment: And yes, next year I am enrolled for an extensive python course!

Comment: @T_R I'm not familiar with the technical terms that you use. Do you mean that there are different Orthogroup files, and that the same orthogroup may appear in multiple files ? Can you extend the question to describe this requirement  - may be sample input and expected output ?

Comment: @T_R Instead of a drink, just make a small donation to your favorite charity :-)

Comment: Ha! I will :-) I have updated the question, including editing the example files so that it is clearer what the extended option looks like. = different treatments per species, but the number of genes per cluster should stay for the species as a whole. e.g. AG + AA is two different treatments of the same species ("AG" as the ID in the orthogroup file)

Comment: This will require some additional changes, I'll try to work on a solution into a different answer